# Align multiple graphics at different indentation levels

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, indentation

I want to include centered graphics with items at different levels in an `enumerate` environment, such that the images line up with each other horizontally.

I currently have

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics{sin.pdf}
  \end{center}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Now is the time for all good men
    \begin{center}
      \includegraphics{cos.pdf}
    \end{center}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

`sin.pdf` and `cos.pdf` are images of exactly the same size.  With the above code, `cos.pdf` is shifted slightly right compared to `sin.pdf`; I want them at exactly the same horizontal position on the page.

I guess maybe what I want is a way to put the image in the center of the physical page, without regard to the indentation of the current paragraph. It is important that the text and graphics be interspersed as shown, so I cannot move both graphs to a float.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: easiest is to use `flushright` rather than `center` and perhaps pad as `\includegraphics{}\hspace*{2cm}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Thanks for the reminder.  I've added a complete example and the output.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks, that was a very useful quick hack (and what I ended up using to meet my deadline).  egreg's answer looks like a more elegant solution which also achieves precise centering, though I still have to think some more about how it works.  In my case it was not so critical that the images be exactly centered as long as they aligned with each other.

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion the only sensible option is to center the images with respect to the overall margin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo is just for the example
\usepackage{showframe,lipsum} % just for the example

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{center*}
  {\list{}{\leftmargin=-\@totalleftmargin}\centering\item\relax}
  {\endlist}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor
  \begin{center*}
    \includegraphics{sin.pdf}
  \end{center*}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Now is the time for all good men
    \begin{center*}
      \includegraphics{cos.pdf}
    \end{center*}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the parameter `\@totalleftmargin` LaTeX keeps the total indentation for the current list environment; in a new list, it updates it with the value given for `\leftmargin`. So in `center*` we have that the indentation level is zero and `\centering` is applied.

Comment: Of course a better idea compared what I have: But what determines the `\leftmargin` on a particular `\item` level?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The first level list uses `\leftmargini`, the second level adds `\leftmarginii` and so on (up to six levels). The values are established by the document class.

Comment: Are you kidding? Just `\leftmargini` etc.? And I thought there is some algorithm behind it ;-) And the values are scaled with different font size, I assume?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer you assume correctly or incorrectly depending, they are set (in article at least) in em units so they scale with the font at the point they are defined (so the `[10,11,12pt]` document options, but they don't scale with `\large` etc

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Well, I referred to `10pt` etc, not to `\large` etc. In this sense you are right: My statement was not clear

Answer (score 3):

For one 'upper' and one 'lower' level, it's possible to give the shifting explicitly
as the sum of

- `\labelwidth`
- `\leftmargin`

However, the leftmargin changes with each level of nesting -- one has to correct the values.

Thanks to the answer by egreg, I realized, that there are predefined `\leftmargini` to `\leftmarginvi` commands, corresponding to the level of nesting.

The difference of `\leftmargini` and `\leftmarginii` will provide the additional right shift of the image.

---

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}%

\newlength{\levelshift}


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor
  \setlength{\levelshift}{\labelwidth+\leftmargini-\leftmarginii}%
  \item \the\leftmargin % show the left margin 1st level
  \begin{center}
    \hspace*{\levelshift}\includegraphics{graph1.pdf}
  \end{center}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item \the\leftmargin % show the left margin 2nd level

  \item Now is the time for all good men
    \begin{center}
      \includegraphics{graph2.pdf}
    \end{center}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is to use `flushright` rather than center and perhaps pad as

```
\begin{flushright}
\includegraphics{foo}\hspace*{2cm}
\end{flushright}
```

If you knw the graphic width you can exactly centre if needed, eg:

```
\begin{flushright}
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{foo}\hspace*{\dimexpr(\textwidth-4cm)/2}
\end{flushright}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be a float `figure` environment with option `[h]`(here), if you are prepared to the fact that sometimes the floats can float, even with this option, and perhaps too munch. This has been discussed in many questions on this site. This could be seem a advantage or a disadvantage. In the latter case, this can be avoided completely with the package `float`, just using the option `[H]` (uppercase).

The advantages of use `figure` instead `center` are the consistency in the spacing between text and images through all the document, the possibility of use traditional captions, and that, may be, jumping to the next page\column (without the surrounding text) is better that break all the column/page because when there are no enough space for the big image (or may be not, it depend of your taste ...).

Example:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{enumerate}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor

   \begin{figure}[h]
   \centering
   \includegraphics[scale=.3]{example-image-a}
   \end{figure}

     \begin{enumerate}
     \item Now is the time for all good men
         \begin{figure}[h]
         \centering
         \includegraphics[scale=.3]{example-image-b}
         \end{figure}
     \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: In many cases I would agree with you.  This particular document happens to be an exam, and I really need each image to appear directly under the text that describes it, and all of them on the same page.

Comment: This will not ensure the images are placed where they're supposed to be; and if one can't be placed, it and all the following will be stacked at the end (or an error will show up if more than 18 floats are delayed). The `[H]` option would do, though.

Comment: @NateEldredge, Then, you can use the option `[H]` for use this approach  (but be sure to include `\usepackage{float}` in the preamble).

Comment: @egreg that's what I meant with "floats can float, even with this option, and perhaps too much".